# 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. (SES)

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email through a contact form on my website but I receive this error:

> 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: KENUBBE@live.se

I need the user to fill in email, name and message then this message should be sent to my domain mail. I tried to send a test mail and it works, but not through the spring boot application.

```
spring.mail.host=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
spring.mail.username=secret
spring.mail.password=secret
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

So my code is:

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new 
SimpleMailMessage();
msg.setFrom("KENUBBE@live.se");
msg.setTo(info@mydomain.se);
msg.setText("Some text");
msg.setSubject("A subject");

javaMailSender.send(msg);
```

but it fails with the error above.

I thought this was going to work when i stepped out of the sandbox mode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you positive you are not in sandbox mode in the `us-east-1` region?

Comment: You have to verify your FROM email in SES console.

Comment: But thats the point, do I need to verify every FROM email that a user puts in the form? And if so, how? Do I verify it in code?

Comment: That is the regulation of Amazon SES that the from email should be a real email address and is verified. You might use an API, See [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html).

Comment: Hmm ok I see.. And if I want to do it with only JavaMailSender with another smtp host and not with SES, do I need to open a port or something for the web server to send the email throught smtp port 587?

Comment: sending is not a matter for port open I think.

Answer (score 2):

The sender email should be verified from the Amazon SES. See below;

> In Amazon SES, an identity is an email address or domain that you use to send email. Before you can send an email using Amazon SES, you must verify each identity that you're going to use as a "From", "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address to prove that you own it. If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also need to verify any email addresses that you send emails to, except for email addresses provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.

You can verify your email from the SES console or by using API,

```
aws ses verify-email-identity --email-address sender@example.com
```

or for multiple accounts, See [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sample-code-bulk-verify.html). This just sends the emails for verification and you need to click or access the attached link to complete the verification.